# how to send Message from Session bean to MessageDrivenBean indirectly

Tags: ejb, jms

I'm wondering how to send a **Message**(javax.jms.Message) from a **MySatefulSessionBean** to **MySingletonBean** and then to **MyMessageDrivenBean**. I'm using Netbeans so I can **Right click** on the *Source code of the Singleton Bean* and choose **Send JMS Message**.

But this would make the Message generated in the **MySingletonBean** to be sent to **MyMessageDrivenBean** when what I actually wanted to do is for the Message to be forwarded from **MySatefulSessionBean** to **MyMessageDrivenBean**.

i.e instead of creating a new Message in MySingleTonBean and sending it to MyMessageDrivenBean for processing, I want the Message that **MySatefulSessionBean** instantiated to be processed by MyMessageDrivenBean's **onMessage**(Message msg) method.

I cannot make MySatefulSessionBean to directly talk with send Message to MyMessageDrivenBean due to personal reason; so the Message should go to the MyMessageDrivenBean indirectly

Can you enlighten me on how to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't actually prepare the message in your stateful session bean, but prepare only the actual payload.

Call your singleton with this payload as a method  parameter, and then keep the JMS message creation an internal detail of the singleton.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Sounds a good plan; I'll see if I can realize why you suggested!

Comment: I mean "what", sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to receive JMS messages in EJBs other then Message Driven Beans. So your MySingletonBean should not receive JMS messages. If you manage to implement it somehow you would get all kind of crazy errors (because of EJB object lifecycle rules).

So rethink you architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Piotr Kochański. But the thing is, I'm not receiving the messages in MySingletonBean. I'm just using it to timestamp an ObjectMessage sent from MySatefulSessionBean and then forward it to MyMessageDrivenBean.

Comment: What do you mean by "forward message"? How it is possible without receving message in MySingletonBean

Comment: Yea, that is confusing for me too. But the specification I am given is that each stand-alone client should send a Message using Stateful Session Bean(MySatefulSessionBean ) to a Chat Manager(MySingletonBean).  Then the Chat Manager sends a Message to the Queue to be processed by MyMessageDrivenBean. <br/> The stand-alone client will not send javax.jms.Message but some Serializable object, that is why I'm sending ObjectMessage to the MyMessageDrivenBean.